# ActionView::MissingTemplate on initial attempt to deliver email with Sidekiq

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq, ruby-on-rails-5

I keep getting errors reported to Honeybadger that various mailer fail from being unable to find the template like: `ActionView::MissingTemplate: Missing template user_mailer/send_invitation with "mailer". Searched in: * "user_mailer"`. I have found a way I can reliably reproduce it is by restarting the Unicorn workers or ssh'ing into the server and using the Rails console to manually trigger the email. To make things more interesting, it only throws this error if I use `deliver_later` but not if I use `deliver_now`. Obviously I want to deliver emails asynchronously, so using `deliver_now` isn't really an option unless I make my own job that trigger the email manually, but that doesn't seem optimal.

**Sidekiq.yml**

```
production:
  :concurrency: 10
  :queues:
    - default
    - mailers
    - elasticsearch
    - searchkick
```

It still delivers the emails on the second attempt, so I'm not sure if this has to do with some loading of Sidekiq or something. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Using Rails 5.0.0, Sidekiq 4.1.4, and ActiveJob 5.0.0.

Answer (score 0):

it tells that there's no required file, simply create the file:
`app/views/user_mailer/send_invitation.html.erb`

Comment: The files exist which is the weird part. They are in that location and with the proper extensions with ASCII encoded characters.

Comment: try to kill the sidekiq precesses and start sidekiq again

Comment: I have done that many times, it always pops back up everytime that I deploy as well, which is several times a day usually.

Comment: Need to take a look. If you can reproduce it, you can contact my by Skype. My nick: inikolay51

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that when I upgraded Sidekiq from `4.0.4` to `4.1.4` it didn't kill my old process so it was hanging around undetected by monit and still plucking jobs from redis. Killed the old processes and it is all fine now. Thanks for every ones feedback.